# How do I simplify this SQL code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need assistance in simplifying the code below. My objective here was to find a product with the prefix and check it with customers in the database. If there are more customers found, place the null or blank. If it is only a record, place the name of the company.

Is there any possible way Rather than using the cursor what is a alternative way of doing this e.g CTE, subquery

```
DECLARE 
     @PartNumber VARCHAR(MAX) -- PartNumber
     ,@PartNumberPrefix VARCHAR(MAX)
     ,@ProductName VARCHAR(MAX)
     ,@Count INT
     ,@CompanyName VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Temp TABLE (PartNumberPreFix VARCHAR(MAX),
                     RealPartNUmber VARCHAR(MAX),
                     CompanyName VARCHAR(MAX)
                    )

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT 
        PART_NUMBER, PRODUCT_NAME,
        (CASE CHARINDEX(' ', PART_NUMBER, 1)  WHEN 0 THEN PART_NUMBER -- empty or single word
    ELSE SUBSTRING(PART_NUMBER, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', PART_NUMBER, 1) - 1) --  multi-word
         END)
    FROM PRODUCT 
    WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 1 
      AND PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = 1 
      AND IS_SELLABLE = 1
      --AND id IN(49,50)

OPEN db_cursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @PartNumber, @ProductName, @PartNumberPrefix   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
     SELECT @PartNumberPrefix = (CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @PartNumber, 1)
     WHEN 0 THEN @PartNumber -- empty or single word
     ELSE SUBSTRING(@PartNumber, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @PartNumber, 1) - 1) -- multi-word
     END)   

     SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_NAME LIKE ('%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@PartNumberPrefix)) + '%') AND TYPE_Id = 2

     SELECT @CompanyName = COMPANY_NAME FROM COMPANY WHERE COMPANY_NAME LIKE ('%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@PartNumberPrefix)) + '%') AND TYPE_Id = 2

     --SELECT 'Before---------'+ @PartNumberPrefix, @CompanyName,    @Count

     IF @Count > 1 OR @CompanyName IS NULL OR @Count = 0
     SET @CompanyName = ''

     --SELECT 'After------------'+ @PartNumberPrefix, @CompanyName

     -- Insert into Temp Table   
     INSERT INTO @Temp (PartNumberPreFix,CompanyName,RealPartNUmber)
     VALUES (@PartNumberPrefix,@CompanyName,@PartNumber) 


     FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @PartNumber,@ProductName,@PartNumberPrefix   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

Comment: Please include a problem statement.  As of the time this comment was posted, you dumped a fairly large SQL query with no explanation.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I do not have any problem with my query. Im asking your suggestion to minimise the coding

Comment: Can you post some sample scripts and sample data (create table and insert)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it with a single query, like the following (moreover it seems to me that column productname is not used).  Can you try it and let me know?

```
WITH A AS (SELECT CASE CHARINDEX(' ', PART_NUMBER, 1)  
            WHEN 0 THEN PART_NUMBER 
            ELSE SUBSTRING(PART_NUMBER, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', PART_NUMBER, 1) - 1) 
            END AS PARTNUMBERPREFIX      
            , PART_NUMBER        
            FROM PRODUCT)
SELECT C.PARTNUMBERPREFIX
    , CASE WHEN RC>1 THEN '' ELSE C.COMPANY_NAME END AS COMPANY_NAME
    , C.PART_NUMBER      
FROM
    (SELECT A.PARTNUMBERPREFIX, A.PART_NUMBER
         , COALESCE(B.COMPANY_NAME,'') AS COMPANY_NAME
         , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PARTNUMBERPREFIX)) + '%') AS RC 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PARTNUMBERPREFIX)) + '%' ORDER BY A.PART_NUMBER) AS RN       
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN COMPANY B ON B.COMPANY_NAME LIKE ('%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(A.PARTNUMBERPREFIX)) + '%') AND B.TYPE_ID=2
    WHERE A.IS_ACTIVE = 1 
      AND A.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = 1 
      AND A.IS_SELLABLE = 1 
      ) C
WHERE RN=1
```